# Node.js - FATAL ERROR: v8::Debug::SetDebugMessageDispatchHandler V8 is no longer usable

Tags: ajax, node.js

When I attempt to run the command 'node server.js' in my ajaxim/server directory, I get this error:
FATAL ERROR: v8::Debug::SetDebugMessageDispatchHandler V8 is no longer usable

I am SO close to getting this AjaxIM to work with the node.js (guest).

Anyone know what I am doing wrong and how to get it working right?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems your V8 is corrupted. You may need to re-install your node again.

Comment: I just did that using the GET and the source file location (http://nodejs.org/dist/node-v0.4.7.tar.gz). How can it be corrupt?